# Polymer test 2.0 freeze with chrome 62

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, polymer, automated-tests, polymer-2.x

When I run my test all goes well. It tell me that all test was ok but after, it never end alone. It tell me

```
Test run ended with great success

chrome 62 (269/0/0)                   
hook: cleanup
chrome 62                CALL title()
chrome 62                GET /session/:sessionID/title
chrome 62                CALL title()
chrome 62                GET /session/:sessionID/title
chrome 62                CALL title()
```

And i've got `CALL title()` and `GET /session/:sessionID/title` undefinitly until I stop manually the test. The problem is when I push to the server and I can't stop it manually so the test doesn't pass.
In chrome 56 I don't have the problem.

My question is, how to resolve this or how to come back to chrome 56 ?

To install chrome I'm using this command :

```
set -xe && wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && apt-get update -yqqq && apt-get install -qq -y google-chrome-stable
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem. I was using this command to run my test :

```
polymer test
```

But with `web-component-tester`, if I use

```
wct
```

It work perfectly !